# Python Selenium driver keeps old data after click

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use Python Selenium to grab Youtube Video URL.  I load the home page first and I click on a random result.  Form that second page, I want to get the suggested video on the right.  But when I do that, the driver just ADDS the suggested video to the list of video found on the home page. I don't know why... so I need to reset or clear something inbetween find_elements

```
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
time.sleep(8)
items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@id='thumbnail'][@class='yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail'][contains(@href, 'watch?v=')]")

for i in items:
    url = i.get_attribute("href")
    print(str(url))

rand = random.choice(items)
rand.click()
time.sleep(10)

# GET SUGGESTED VIDEO ON THE RIGHT
yt_right_pane_items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//a[@id='thumbnail'][@class='yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail'][contains(@href, 'watch?v=')]")

for i in yt_right_pane_items:
    url = i.get_attribute("href")
    print(str(url))
```

The OUTPUT of the HOMEPAGE:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YuC4ZJJI5c
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyUIEU1qW1w&t=13147s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9-ekUCFCr0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BoVAOpSiD_A
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJqDZKAxOOY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJL1k37T6r8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1dhGnZIxfI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y57jYUogWFs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4V0e9IpzSfs
```

The Second output = Videos of the first find_elements + videos of second find_elements

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YuC4ZJJI5c
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FyUIEU1qW1w&t=13147s
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9-ekUCFCr0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BoVAOpSiD_A
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJqDZKAxOOY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nJL1k37T6r8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o1dhGnZIxfI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y57jYUogWFs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4V0e9IpzSfs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jHa20EBYPU8
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ImnTNcqtvlY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppiIs2YoFqo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3TFt5oqDJU
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BisnRXb_sk0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l5Pjhl1vgUw
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvsZKNYwHt0
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L6VBHflOeuY
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MPRbX7ACh8
```

On the second find_elements, I only want to get the NEW video form the page that was clicked on.

Comment: The reason is quite simple you have two list `items` and `yt_right_pane_items` although they are two different list however you are supplying the same xpath `//a[@id='thumbnail'][@class='yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail'][contains(@href, 'watch?v=')]` therefore the new list with suggested videos does have the one before `rand.click()`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why... what is the solution... the XPATH is the same on the homepage and on the video page, so how can I get a fresh list. I though by using 2 different variable names for my list would do it....  I'm not sure what I should do.   I even tried calling them both "items" and I get the same problem

Comment: forget about the XPath for a minute, when you click on ` GET SUGGESTED VIDEO ` do you see the videos from the `items` list?

Comment: yes, the first click works. It loads the video page that was selected at random. This is ok. Then I scrape the URL on the second page, then if I try clicking on a URL of the second page, I get an error that item is not clickable because it's grabbing an item from the list (that is form the homepage)

Comment: I also tried:  items.clear()  before loading the second URL on the 2nd page, same problem

Comment: code gives correct result. Second page has these links in HTML but hidden. You would have to change xpath and search only in visible part - `//div[@id='columns']`. Or you `set()` to remove previous results - `new = set(second) - set(first)`

Comment: and if you only sugestion on right then `//div[@id='related']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not `Selenium` nor `list` but `YouTube` - it keeps these links but hidden.

Your `xpath` searchs all links - even hidden - but it should search only in visible part

```
//div[@id='columns']
```

Full xpath

```
//div[@id='columns']//a[@id='thumbnail'][@class='yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail'][contains(@href, 'watch?v=')]
```

---

And if you want only `SUGGESTED VIDEO ON THE RIGHT` then search in

```
//div[@id='related']
```

Full xpath

```
//div[@id='related']//a[@id='thumbnail'][@class='yt-simple-endpoint inline-block style-scope ytd-thumbnail'][contains(@href, 'watch?v=')]
```

---

---

Other method is to use `set()` which removes duplicated elements

```
new = list( set(second_list) - set(first_list) )

duplicated = list( set(second_list) & set(first_list) )
```

It can be useful because you can get duplicated in suggested from all pages.